# Ruby On Rails: Form fields that refer to the same object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form with several fields that are associated with the same object_name `:result`. I have some jquery/javascript that hides all but one of these fields depending on a field that is chosen earlier in the form. How can I ensure that when I hit the submit button, the `:result` object is given the correct value, depending on which field is actually shown? It seems that since all the other fields are just hidden, rails gets confused as to which `:result` should be used.

```
<div class="Collection1 desc">

    <div id="pf" class="result" style="display: none;">
    <%= f.label :result %>
    <%= f.radio_button :result, 'pass' %> Pass
    <%= f.radio_button :result, 'fail' %> Fail
    <br><br>
    </div>

    <div id="int" class ="result" style="display: none;">
    <%= f.label :result %>
    <%= f.number_field :result %>
    </div>

    <div id="text" class ="result" style="display: none;">  
    <%= f.label :result %>
    <%= f.text_field :result %>
    </div>

    <div id="area" class ="result" style="display: none;">
    <%= f.label :result %>
    <%= f.text_area :result %>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also disable the fields that you are hiding. This way they will not get submitted with the form.